# How do I align the anchor links and lists in sidebars?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: verdana, georgia;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*****************Blocks*********************/

.navbar  {
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 90px;
 width: 100%;
 top:0px;
 margin-left: 250px;
}

.topContent {
 background-color: #eceff1;
 height: 200px;
 width:100%;
 margin-left: 250px;
}

.mainContent {
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
 height: 800px;
 width:800px;
 margin-left: 250px;
 
}
.leftSideNav1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #37474f;
   
}
.leftSideNav2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 80px;
    background-color: #263238;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

/*****************Elements*********************/

.leftSideNav1__lists a{
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #eee;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
}


.leftSideNav2 {
 font-size: 12px;
}

.leftSideNav2 .leftSideNav2__lists > ul{
 padding-top: 80px;
}

.leftSideNav2__lists ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>
        <div class="topContent">
        </div>
        <div class="mainContent">
        </div>
        <div class="leftSideNav1">
            <div class="leftSideNav1__lists">
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-home w3-large"></i> -->
                <i class="Tiny material-icons">home</i><br>
                <a href="#">Home</a><br>
                <i class="material-icons">pause</i><br>
                <a href="#">YouTubers</a><br>
                <i class="material-icons">assignment</i><br>
                <a href="#">Campaigns</a><br>
                <i class="material-icons">message</i><br>
                <a href="#">Messages</a><br>
                <i class="material-icons">pause</i><br>
                <a href="#">Videos</a><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="leftSideNav2">
            <div class="leftSideNav2__lists">
                <ul class="leftSideNav2__list1">Videos
                    <li>Action Required</li>
                    <li>Fund YouTuber</li>
                    <li>Hired & Funded</li>
                    <li>Edit Requested</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="leftSideNav2__list2">Proposals
                    <li>New</li>
                    <li>Declined</li>
                    <li>Changes Required</li>
                    <li>Changes Declined</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="leftSideNav2__list3">Approvals
                    <li>Waiting for Approval</li>
                    <li>Approved / Completed</li>
                    <li>Video in Dispute</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/KXqvRE)

I have an issue with the anchor links and lists in the sidebars. I am unable to align the anchor links and lists in the 2 sidebars. I am trying to apply the CSS properties but they aren't applying perhaps due to improper hierarchical style of applying.

Currently, this is how it looks:

[image: Img1]

But this is how I want it to look:

[image: img2]

Comment: You are required to post your markup or code here, not a third party site or your own, which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: Is that why you downvoted? There are tonnes of questions using JSfiddle, codepen and plnkr? Are they all going to disappear? I didn't post it because I don't like to make question too long. You better find a better logic to downvote next time.

Comment: You can use those to compliment your question but not replace it. Read the link I gave you. If you don't supply your markup here, this question will eventually be closed.

Comment: @HebleV: Rob is quite right. In fact, there is a close reason for this very purpose - see the [mcve] article for more info. It looks like someone added in the necessary code for you.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thank you @Rob

Answer (score 1):

you can do it setting the parent container

```
.leftSideNav1__lists{
 text-align:center;
}
```

an also removing the left margin from each a tag..
[codepen](https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/GMEONg)

Comment: Hey Thank you. How do I add space between the anchor links of .leftSideNav1 and also the lists of .leftSideNav2?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: verdana, georgia;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*****************Blocks*********************/

.navbar  {
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 90px;
 width: 100%;
 top:0px;
 margin-left: 250px;
}

.topContent {
 background-color: #eceff1;
 height: 200px;
 width:100%;
 margin-left: 250px;
}

.mainContent {
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
 height: 800px;
 width:800px;
 margin-left: 250px;
 
}
.leftSideNav1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #37474f;
   
}
.leftSideNav2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 80px;
    background-color: #263238;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

/*****************Elements*********************/

.leftSideNav1__lists a{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #eee;
 text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.leftSideNav2 {
 font-size: 12px;
}

.leftSideNav2 .leftSideNav2__lists > ul{

}

.leftSideNav2__lists ul {
 list-style: none;

}

.leftSideNav1__lists > i{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>
        <div class="topContent">
        </div>
        <div class="mainContent">
        </div>
        <div class="leftSideNav1">
            <div class="leftSideNav1__lists">
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-home w3-large"></i> -->
                <i class="Tiny material-icons">home</i>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                 <i class="material-icons">pause</i>
                <a href="#">YouTubers</a>
                <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
                <a href="#">Campaigns</a>
                <i class="material-icons">message</i>
                <a href="#">Messages</a>
                <i class="material-icons">pause</i>
                <a href="#">Videos</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="leftSideNav2">
            <div class="leftSideNav2__lists">
                <ul class="leftSideNav2__list1">Videos
                    <li>Action Required</li>
                    <li>Fund YouTuber</li>
                    <li>Hired & Funded</li>
                    <li>Edit Requested</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="leftSideNav2__list2">Proposals
                    <li>New</li>
                    <li>Declined</li>
                    <li>Changes Required</li>
                    <li>Changes Declined</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="leftSideNav2__list3">Approvals
                    <li>Waiting for Approval</li>
                    <li>Approved / Completed</li>
                    <li>Video in Dispute</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Try this.

Comment: Not exactly how I wanted. if you see the leftSideNav2 lists are going up. Check the img2